# Loading GZIP JSON file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, gzip

I have gzipped json file using below algorithm (from:  [java gzip can't keep original file's extension name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564138/java-gzip-cant-keep-original-files-extension-name))

```
private static boolean compress(String inputFileName, String targetFileName){
         boolean compressResult=true;
         int BUFFER = 1024*4;
         byte[] B_ARRAY = new byte[BUFFER]; 
         FileInputStream fins=null;
         FileOutputStream fout=null;
         GZIPOutputStream zout=null;
         try{
             File srcFile=new File(inputFileName);
             fins=new FileInputStream (srcFile);
             File tatgetFile=new File(targetFileName);
             fout = new FileOutputStream(tatgetFile);
             zout = new GZIPOutputStream(fout);
             int number = 0; 
             while((number = fins.read(B_ARRAY, 0, BUFFER)) != -1){
                 zout.write(B_ARRAY, 0, number);  
             }
         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             compressResult=false;
         }finally{
             try {
                zout.close();
                fout.close();
                fins.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                compressResult=false;
            }
         }
         return compressResult;
    }
```

I am returning the JSON

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
response.setHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","gzip");
response.sendRedirect(filePathurl);
```

or

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(filePathurl).forward(request, response);
```

Trying to access the JSON object using AJAX code as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : url,
    headers : {'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip'},
    dataType : 'text',
```

The output I see is the binary data, not the decompressed JSON string. Any suggestion on how to make this work?
Note that the Browsers I am using (IE, Chrome, FF) supports gzip as all my static contents which are gzipped by Apache are rendered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

By using:

```
response.sendRedirect(filePathurl);
```

You are creating another request/response. The headers you have defined are no longer associated with the file that actually gets sent.

Rather than sending a redirect, you need to load up your file and stream it in the same response.

Use Fiddler or another request viewer to see this.

Comment: thanks for your response. Fiddler confirms your view; I tried forward method also, in which fiddler shows the correct header, and when I view the uncompressed text, i can see the JSON; but the AJAX code is not reading the output as JSON. I am looking for solution (if feasible) to avoid reading and streaming the file.

Answer (score -1):

We can not override Accept-Encoding from browser/js etc anymore.