# Compress json array list in java(Spring mvc) and decompress it in javascript(angular js)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, spring-mvc, gzip

How to compress json array list in java(Spring mvc) and decompress it in javascript(angular js) ?
Have  tried to gzip json by adding a filter in java but json data size is still the same in response.

Comment: Would this QnA help? 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676831/how-to-compress-json-in-java-and-decompression-in-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676831/how-to-compress-json-in-java-and-decompression-in-javascript

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? (Also, this smells of premature optimization. Do you actually NEED to compress the String?)

Comment: Isn't your server already serving gzipped responses?

Comment: In Tomcat server have enabled gzip compression its working for js,html,css files but application/json responses are not compressed

Comment: I remember, a long time ago, something called [`hpack`](https://github.com/WebReflection/json.hpack) and [`jsonpack`](https://github.com/sapienlab/jsonpack). It was available in a number of languages.

Comment: @ Xotic750  My idea to compress json data is decrease the loading time as the json data size is more than 6 mb I had a look at jsonpack its a JavaScript program to pack and unpack JSON data so after loading its no point of compressing the data in javascript. I want something that compresses json data in java and decompresses it in javascript